# Logrotate in linux to handle log data loss

Tags: logs, logrotate

We are using linux logrotate for rotating our log files,

Example :

```
/location/tomcat/logs/* /location/jboss/log/* {
      copytruncate
      daily
      rotate 10
      compress
      size 20M
      olddir rotated
      create 0644 test test
}
```

As per the copy truncate definition given in LINUX,

```
copytruncate
          Truncate  the  original log file in place after creating a copy,
          instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new
          one,  It  can be used when some program can not be told to close
          its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending)  to  the
          previous log file forever.  Note that there is a very small time
          slice between copying the file and truncating it, so  some  log-
          ging  data  might be lost.  When this option is used, the create
          option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in  place.
```

So there will be a data loss in log file during rotate process. I noticed around 5 to 20 seconds of log loss, Is there a way / configuration to do the same process without data loss?

Answer (score 1):

I know that in syslog-ng, you can set the output filename to use variables, including things like the date, so it would automatically start writing to a new file at 12:00am on the new day, with zero loss.

It requires changing your syslog program to syslog-ng, though. But the flexibility sounds like exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could move from logfile logging and rotating with `logrotate` to `journald` logging using `systemd-cat -t indentifier cmdline`. Setup log/entry sizes in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` or use `journalctl --vacuum-size=, --vacuum-time=, --vacuum-files=`

Another way is to `logrotate` once a day by using the prerotate/postrotate feature to stop the servers, rotate the log and start the servers again. The logrotation time is depending on your systemd `logrotate.timer` or (ana)cron job, which could be timed to 4am or whenever is low to zero traffic.

```
prerotate
    # stop jboss/tomcat server 
endscript

daily
rotate 10
compress
size 20M

postrotate
    #start servers
endscript
```

Comment: I cannot stop the server, my need is while logrotate is doing truncate I should not loose the data, Is there a way for it? Can u suggest me any configuration? @Michael D

Comment: is using journald an option? Read this https://www.loggly.com/blog/why-journald/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it for `Catalina` logs:

```
/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out {
        daily
        size 100m
        compressext .gz
        compress
        delaycompress
        compressoptions "-9"
        dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s
        ifempty
        copytruncate
        prerotate
                SIZE=$(stat --printf='%s' /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out)
                /bin/bash -c "tail -c +$SIZE -f /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out > /var/log/tomcat/tmp.log" &
        endscript
        postrotate
                pgrep tail | xargs kill -9
                cat /var/log/tomcat/tmp.log >> /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out
                rm /var/log/tomcat/tmp.log -f
        endscript
}
```

You may optionally specify `-s` with `tail` to decrease refresh interval of `tail` command itself. And because you use `-c` option, it's fast.